# Partial derivative coordinates of tangent vectors and covectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, partial-derivative, duality-theorems

I am learning differential geometry and it has triggered a more general question about the partial derivatives, as they relate to the coordinate functions of vectors and covectors.

Using the following for vectors
$${\partial \over \partial f } = \sum a^i {\partial \over \partial x^i }$$

where
$$a^i = {\partial x^i \over \partial f}$$

and for covectors
$$df = \sum b^i dx^i $$

where
$$ b^i = {\partial f \over \partial x^i}$$

Now using the cylindrical coordinate frame as an example with $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ we find $$dr = \cos \theta dx + \sin \theta dy $$

so $ {\partial r \over \partial x} = \cos \theta $

and since $x = r \cos \theta $ we also have $ {\partial x \over \partial r} = \cos \theta $

Doing the same for $y$ we get the same coordinate functions in the vector and in the covector

$${\partial \over \partial r } = \cos \theta {\partial \over \partial x } + \sin \theta {\partial \over \partial y } $$

looking at $d\theta$ however, we get that

$${\partial \theta \over \partial x} = - {1\over r} \sin \theta $$
$${\partial \theta \over \partial y} =  {1\over r} \cos \theta $$

while

$${\partial x \over \partial \theta} = - r \sin \theta$$
$${\partial y \over \partial \theta} =  r \cos \theta$$

... leading to the unit vector ${1 \over r}{\partial \over \partial \theta}$ and its covector $r d\theta$, which similarly share the same coordinate functions

Now, the question... what can we say about the relationship between $\partial f \over \partial x$ and $\partial x \over \partial f$ ? Specifically I am looking for a condition in which the coordinates of a vector and covector are equal as in the attitude matrix of a frame field of orthonormal vectors. I am able to show that if vectors and covectors have the same coordinates that they will be unit vectors, but I am looking for the reverse proof, the condition on which vectors and covectors will have the same coordinates $a^i = b^i$

My own attempt so far is as follows, considering coordinate functions constant and integrating $df$ ...

$$f = \sum b^i x^i + c $$

$$df ({\partial \over \partial f} ) = {\partial \over \partial f} (f) = (\sum a^i {\partial \over \partial x^i}) \circ (\sum b^j x^j + c) $$

and presuming ${\partial x^i \over \partial x^j} = \delta _{ij}$ then

$$ df ({\partial \over \partial f} ) = \sum a^i b^i $$ and of course

$$ df ({\partial \over \partial f} ) = 1$$

so, $\sum a^i b^i = 1$

Now $ ||E_1||^2 = \sum a^i a^i $ and if the coordinates are equal, then $a^i = b^i$ so $\sum a^i a^i = 1$ so we have a unit vector / covector.

So unit length is a condition for the vector and covector coordinates to be the same, but is this condition also sufficient?

Comment: Typically $f$ denotes a function on your manifold. Given a chart $(U, \phi) = (U, x^1,...,x^n)$, we have that, $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Bigr|_p, j = 1,...,n$$ becomes a basis for the tangent space $T_pM$ where $p \in U$. These are tangent vectors due to the fact that they are derivations as seen by the relation, $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} \Bigr|_{p} f:= \frac{\partial}{\partial r^j} \Bigr|_{\phi(p)} f \circ \phi^{-1}$$ where $r^1,...,r^j$ are the standard coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So I am very confused when you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}$. To me that makes no sense.

Comment: In the requirement of the dual basis $E^i(E_j) = \delta_{ij}$

We have

$$ df ({\partial \over \partial f}) = 1 $$

Write out the whole thing ...

$$ {\partial \over \partial f} = \sum {\partial x^i \over \partial f}{\partial \over \partial x^i}$$

now plugin any $x^j$ and you get

$$ {\partial x^j \over \partial f} = {\partial x^j \over \partial f} $$

... this was my reasoning in trying to tie it all together with this notation. It does at least seem fair that if our covector is essentially $df$ then our vector should be $\partial \over \partial f$ does it not?

Comment: No. $\frac{\partial}{\partial f}$ does not make sense for a general function $f$. It only makes sense for real or complex valued $f$ i.e $f: U \to \mathbb{K}$ where $K = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If you are saying it is a tangent vector then how do you define its operation on smooth functions?

Comment: Fair enough. I am really just thinking of a real valued function here not a general mapping, trying to understand the deeper reason why for an orthonormal frame, the basis and the dual basis share the same attitude matrix (presumably with some condition). For instance the conversion between Cartesian and Cylindrical coordinates can be described by such real valued functions for each new coordinate i.e. $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and the appropriate row of the attitude for this frame can be entirely derived from this. Yet, you can also get there from $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$